# Passing a dir into a bean constructor

Tags: java, spring, constructor

I have the following bean setup

```
    <bean id="server-engine"
    class="RuleEngineRESJSE">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="package.rulesengine.log" />
</bean>
```

However I get the error:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The value of rulesLogProperty was not found
```

The constructor simply takes a string argument for the rulesLogProperty

```
    public RuleEngineRESJSE(String rulesLogProperty) throws IOException {

    if(rulesLogProperty == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("The rulesLogProperty value is expected");

    this.log = System.getProperty(rulesLogProperty);

    if(log == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("The value of rulesLogProperty was not found");

    init();
}
```

so I see the exception is being thrown. which would make me think that:

```
this.log = System.getProperty(rulesLogProperty)
```

is the issue but why?

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks set up right to me. I'd assume that the package.rulesengine.log just isn't in the right location although that seems too simple.